# Amazon connect get user input using lex doesnt send typing event

Tags: amazon-lex

i have a setup where i used amazon lex for amazon connect get user input. And I also use amazon connect chatjs framework to work for front end. My problem is, amazon connect with lex to get a user input doesn’t send typing event to the frontend leading to typing bubble not to work. I’m just wondering if this is somehow expected because the amazon connect starts on sending typing event if the agent from CCP start typing something. So it looks like to me that typing event only works to an Agent participant typing and will not work for lex.